# Posting To Facebook Fan Page As Admin Using PHP

Tags: php, facebook

I've been trying to find a way to past to a facebook fan page (which I'm admin) from my application using php, but can't find a way to do it.  Any help?

Comment: Please post the code that you wrote for this, outlining the problems it may have.

Comment: been trying to work from this: http://blog.theunical.com/facebook-integration/simple-steps-to-publish-on-facebook-fan-page-using-php/  But I think this method is outdated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are the admin of the page, you just need have the `publish_stream` permission and using the new PHP-SDK you post to your page the same way you do for your own feed:

```
$facebook->api("/PAGE_ID/feed","POST",array("message"=>"Hello Page!"));
```

[image]